# Infinispan Configurations Using property file

Tags: properties, configuration, infinispan

Is it possible to load values for infinispan-config.xml file from some property file so that we can get rid of hard coded values. If possible then can somebody show me the way how i load property file in infinispan-config.xml file because there is no Pre defined tag for configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by setting respective system properties.

For example here is one specific Infinispan configuration file which is using this approach: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/main/core/src/test/resources/configs/string-property-replaced.xml

and here is a test which is working with that file: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/main/core/src/test/java/org/infinispan/configuration/StringPropertyReplacementTest.java

This looks to be the most straightforward way how to achieve this.
The last thing which needs to be done is to simply read all lines in your configuration file and put them correctly to system properties.

Comment: Thanks tsykora. But is it possible way that we can load property file in our xml file. As infinispan doesnot defined any specific tag for loading property file

Comment: As i want to override these values maxEntries strategy lifespan maxidle etc from property file                               <namedCache
        name="LOOKUP">
        <eviction maxEntries="10" strategy="FIFO"/>
        <expiration  wakeUpInterval="500" lifespan="60000"  maxIdle="120000"/>
    </namedCache>

Comment: Infinispan does _not_ something like this in configuration schema. There is no tag like <cacheFromExternalFile>/path/to/file</cacheFromExternalFile>. If you want to override values in your infinispan.xml file by some values from property file, you probably need to do it like this:

Comment: <namedCache name="LOOKUP"> <eviction maxEntries="${maxEntriesFromSysPropFile}" strategy="${evictionStrategyFromSysPropFile}"/> <expiration wakeUpInterval="${wakeUp}" lifespan="${lifespan}" maxIdle="${maxIdle}"/> </namedCache>. Can you explain your use case if it does not help?

Comment: Or, there is another possible way. You can use Maven transformation options with xsl stylesheets but this is even more complicated and you can avoid this.